# The microsoft ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider is not register on the local machine

Tags: ms-access

I have created a Windows application in 32 bit and it works correctly under 32 bit Windows.

But when I want to debug it in 64 bit windows an error has been shown :  `The microsoft ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider is not register on the local machine`

I have installed Access engine for 64 bit but the error is shown again .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a well known problem.

Download and install [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)